# Function for ordering a list alphabetically?

Tags: python, list

I need a function that will order my list in alphabetical order, returning `False` if the list is not ordered alphabetically and `True` if it is.

It should work like this:

```
>>> ordered(['Cilka', 'Berta', 'Dani', 'Ana', 'Ema'])
False
>>> ordered(["Ana", "Berta", "Cilka", "Dani", "Ema"])
True
```

Names are in Slovenian language, don't mind them.

I have written this:

```
def ordered(s):
```

`s` is the name of the list. Can you help me?

Comment: *"I have written this"* - how good of you to struggle all the way to the end of the function definition before dumping your homework on us.

Comment: Your title says you want to order a list, you question says you want to know if a list is ordered. Which is it? [Please edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26710938/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Since the ordering on strings is already the alphabetical one, you can just use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
def ordered(lst):
    return lst == sorted(lst)
```

#### Example

```
>>> ordered(['Cilka', 'Berta', 'Dani', 'Ana', 'Ema'])
False
>>> ordered(["Ana", "Berta", "Cilka", "Dani", "Ema"])
True
```

The problem with this approach is that it produces the sorted version of the list before comparing. So, if the list is really big you can just check if every element precedes the following in the lexicographic order:

```
def ordered2(lst):
    return all(lst[i] <= lst[i + 1] for i in xrange(len(lst) - 1))
```

#### Example

The side effect is that this one produces the sorted version of the list. If the list is really big you can just check if every element precedes the following in the lexicographic order:

```
>>> ordered2(['Cilka', 'Berta', 'Dani', 'Ana', 'Ema'])
False
>>> ordered2(["Ana", "Berta", "Cilka", "Dani", "Ema"])
True
```

Or if you really want to be super-lazy and super-pythonic you can use `izip` and `islice`:

```
from itertools import izip, islice

def ordered3(lst):
    return all(x <= y for x, y in izip(islice(lst, 0), islice(lst, 1)))
```

#### Time comparison

Let's generate a big list of shuffled numbers (the method works for everything that is comparable and has an ordering):

```
In [20]: from random import shuffle

In [21]: lst = range(10000)

In [22]: shuffle(lst)

In [23]: %timeit ordered(lst)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.48 ms per loop

In [24]: %timeit ordered2(lst)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 696 ns per loop

In [25]: %timeit ordered3(lst)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 602 ns per loop
```

As you can see `ordered2` and `ordered3` are way faster than `ordered`. That's because the initial sort operation implies an `O(n·ln)` cost, not implied in the other two methods.

Comment: def urejen(s):
    return s == sorted(s)

urejen(['Cilka', 'Berta', 'Dani', 'Ana', 'Ema'])

what do i have to do, so it will print false or true ? because it doesn't print it...

Comment: add a print before invoking the function? `print urejen(['Cilka', 'Berta', 'Dani', 'Ana', 'Ema'])`